# Querying with WHERE, AND & ILIKE

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, where-clause

I have this 3 column:

[image]

When I'm using this query:

```
SELECT "code", "desc", "lt_status_uuid" FROM "product_info" 
WHERE 
"lt_status_uuid" = '1f9d541b-5812-4d81-a997-6fb15ed397b1'
AND
"desc" ILIKE 
'%nk%' OR "code" ILIKE '%nk%';
```

I will get 1 record even though `lt_status_uuid` `1f9d541b-5812-4d81-a997-6fb15ed397b1` does not exist in my table. I was actually expecting no record returned.

How can I query based on `lt_status_uuid` and if it's exist; the `ILIKE` will trigger?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about making the query like this? WHERE 
"lt_status_uuid" = '1f9d541b-5812-4d81-a997-6fb15ed397b1'
AND
**(**"desc" ILIKE 
'%nk%' OR "code" ILIKE '%nk%'**)**;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses because of the precedence of `AND` and `OR`. `AND` has higher precedence, and is evaluated first. Because of that, your code is being interpreted as

```
SELECT "code", "desc", "lt_status_uuid" FROM "product_info" 
WHERE 
("lt_status_uuid" = '1f9d541b-5812-4d81-a997-6fb15ed397b1'
AND
"desc" ILIKE 
'%nk%') OR "code" ILIKE '%nk%';
```

Adding parentheses clarifies what you're asking, so that the evaluation order is what you actually want:

```
SELECT "code", "desc", "lt_status_uuid" FROM "product_info" 
WHERE 
"lt_status_uuid" = '1f9d541b-5812-4d81-a997-6fb15ed397b1'
AND
("desc" ILIKE 
'%nk%' OR "code" ILIKE '%nk%');
```